# sorting a linked list in ascending order c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

So i have a singly linked list. New items are added to the front of the chain, so if you added 8,4,10 the list would be 10,4,8. Anyway, now I am trying to sort the list after the insertion is completed except I just cannot figure out how to then loop through these numbers and re-arrange them in ascending order. I'll probably take a break here and come back in a bit, hopefully that will help me figure this out.

*this is a project for school, so suggesting I use some other container is not helpful in my case except being informative as I cannot change what I am working with.

Layout of the list

```
struct Node
    {
      int Item;      // User data item
      Node * Succ;   // Link to the node's successor
    };

unsigned Num //number of items in the list
Node * Head //pointer to the first node
```

My insertion function looks like this

```
Node * newOne;
newOne = new (nothrow) Node;
newOne->Item = X;
newOne->Succ = NULL;

if(Head == NULL)
{
        Head = newOne;
}
else
{
        newOne->Succ = Head;
        Head = newOne;
}
Num++;
```

Comment: What other limitations were put on the assignment?  Can you copy the contents to another container for sorting?

Comment: This is really difficult. I doubt that the correct solution will just come to you even after a break (although you may be a genius, who knows). Have a look here for the best solution http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html

Comment: Maybe you should sort it while inserting? I.e put the element into the right position...

Comment: If you first make a swap function to exchange to adjecent elements in your list it should be fairly straight forward to implement bubble sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: It's true, bubble sort is easier, mergesort is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done two ways, i am not going to post the code, but hopefully this will help you.

**1. Arrange in ascending order during insertion**

This involves adding the elements always in ascending order. For example if the link list is

```
            | 1  |
```

and you add 5 the new link list is

```
           |1|--->|5|
```

and if you add 3 next it should be

```
           |1| ---> |3| ----> |5|
```

This involves comparison of the new element till you find the correct position.

**2. Wait till all the elements are inserted, arrange in ascending order.**

This would involve using a sorting algorithm like merge sort, insertion sort, bubble sort etc on the elements of linklist.

After the sorting of the numbers is done, rewrite the linklist in the correct order.

Example:

if  link list contains

```
        3 2 5 1 6
```

After sorting through an algorithm

```
  1 2 3 5 6 (stored in an array)
```

Now loop through the link list and replace the elements in correct order.

**Be careful if the nodes contain other elements, those other elements would need to be replaced too.**

Note: This requires extra memory, the other way would to swap the nodes which would take longer time. Unless the link-list contains a large number of nodes(thus making memory important) or has other elements, using array  would be simpler.

Comment: Thank you, this made a lot of sense. I ended up going with method 2 as there is no other information other than that int. So I made a vector, sorted that, and then updated the nodes based on the order of the vector! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a singly linked list is nasty to code (unless you like linear sorts such as bubble sort or insertion sort). It's much simpler to copy the contents into a vector, sort the vector, and then rebuild the list.